# jquery dialog position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am unable to get my jquery dialog to the top of the page.  I have tried everything i saw online but it just wont move.  Here are a few things i have tried:

```
$('#dlgChange').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '800',
    resizable: false,
    title: Details,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: window,  //I also tried $('.right-container) - this is the full right side of my page
        collision: "none"
    }
});

$('#dlgChange').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: '800',
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Details',
    position: 'top',
});
```

I have tried to adjust the position after the dialog was open:

```
$('#dlgChange').dialog('option', 'position', 'top');
```

Nothing is moving the dialog to the top of the page.  It always stays in the center.  I need to move it up because the bottom of the dialog is moving off the page.  I have jquery-ui version 1.12.1 and bootstrap 3.3.6. The css that seems to be causing the issue is the bold line below.

```
 .ui-dialog {    
            left: 50% !important;
            **top: 50% !important;**
            margin-left: -175px !important;
            margin-top: -175px !important;
            position: fixed;
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var yourPosition = {
  my: "center top",
  at: "center top+50"
};
$(function() {
  $("#dlgChange").dialog({
    position: yourPosition,
  });
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/bb064jdf/2/)

Comment: Thank you but this did not move the dialog for me.  I included your code after the dialog was opened and it stayed in the same spot.

Comment: @user2370664 I added `jquery-ui.css` to my fiddle and tested again it work properly. I think you have another `css` that it causes this problem. Could you add fiddle to your question?

Comment: You are exactly right.  There was another css causing the problem.  jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui-all.css were both loaded.  Thank You

Comment: @user2370664 Please up-vote my answer for knowing and helping other people that it helps you because some people only see the up-voted answers.